# Relationship generation fails in Entity Framework 5 when using GUIDs and clustered indexes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

re have started using Entity Framework 5 with in ASP.NET MVC4 project in VS2012.
Since the database has been designed through a tool, we are creating our model based on the database.
The database uses GUIDs as primary keys.

When we generated the model, there were no relationship created between the classes. 
After a lot of trial-and-error we found out that the problem was caused by the clustered index that was built on the foreign key GUID columns. Once we removed those from the database and recreated out model, all relationships were generated as they should.

Has anyone else experienced the same issues or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: I doubt that an index being a clustered index has any effect on your program.